# Get "npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0" Error when running "npm start" on angular 2 quickstart after downloading from bitbucket

Tags: node.js, angular, darwin

I'm trying to get Auth0 working on angualr 2 project,

I'm using the code Auth0 allow you to download, from their sample project, and it works when I run npm install and then npm start.

But then if I upload it to bitbucket, and trying to download it again, after running npm install and npm start I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGPM5.jpg)

1. Do you know what this error means?
2. and do you know how I can fix it?
3. In general how is the best way to debug these types of errors?

If you would like to play with the code you can download it from here: 
https://bitbucket.org/tommycp2/integrify

Answer (score 0):

Good News, I just worked it out with this solution: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10891

I needed to update the typings.